# Vba excel convert cell to Hebrew currency (ILS)

Tags: vba, excel, currency

I am trying to convert cells with numbers to Hebrew currency format, instead of getting  the sign of currency I get question mark sign like in an example attached.
I've rerecorded a macro but it just doesn't seem to work

[image]

```
Range("I4", "I" & LastRow).NumberFormat = _
    "_ [$?-40D] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$?-40D] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$?-40D] * ""-""??_ ;_ @_ "
```

Thank in advance, I would appreciate a lot If someone could answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA editor doesn't recognize the Hebrew currency symbol so you can use an ASCII character instead.  The one your looking for is ChrW(8362).  I found the correct character code from [this website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aa/index.htm).

Example:

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = _
"_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * ""-""tt_ ;_ @_ "
```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well, it pretty much did the job, Thanks a lot.

'Range("I4", "I" & LastRow).NumberFormat = _
        "_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * #,##0.00_ ;_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * -#,##0.00_ ;_ [$" & ChrW(8362) & "-10D] * ""-""_ ;_ @_ "'
this worked better since when 0 was there it was writing "-tt" ,thanks.